# $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ}$ admits idempotents

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

> I need to show that if $n$ is not a prime power,then $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ}$ admits idempotents $\neq 0,1$

I noticed this thing for $\mathbb{Z_6}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ and few more but how do we show that there will always exists such $a$?

Comment: If $n$ is not a prime power, there are at least two distinct primes $p,q$ dividing $n$. How are the idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ related to $p$ and $q$?

Comment: they're power of prime!

Comment: Hmm, too bad, though not entirely unrelated. Try $18$.

Comment: Your question has been discussed in [Idempotents in $Z\_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175963/idempotents-in-z-n). Basically Chinese Remainder Theorem allows you to reduce to the case, where $n$ is a prime power. The total number of idempotents is $2^k$, where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Comment: $6^2=6$ in $\mathbb{Z_{18}}$ and $16^{16}=16$ in $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$

Comment: No, $6^2 = 36 \equiv 0 \pmod{18}$. But $10^2 \equiv 10 \pmod{18}$. So it's not prime powers.

Comment: oops! yeah got it

Comment: Neeraj, what you could notice from  Daniel's example ($10$ an idempotent modulo $18$) is that $10\equiv1\pmod9$ and $10\pmod 0\pmod2$, so $10$ is an (trivial) idempotent modulo both the prime power factors of $18$. That's the way it always pans out.

Comment: In the post which is already answered most of the proofs rely on CRT , can we do it without CRT?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal If you can give a real reason you should "do it without" a very useful staple of ring theory, then I will attempt to do so.