# $f(x) = x$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]$ factors as $(3x+4)(4x+3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

This question has a lot of parts so I'll post each part separately.

> First, show $f(x) = x$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]$ factors as $(3x+4)(4x+3)$

I am trying long division. I cannot divide $x$ by either $(3x+4)$ or by $(4x+3)$ mod 6. Anything multiplied by 3 is either 3 or 0 mod 6. And 4,2,0 mod 6 when a number is multiplied by 4.

Comment: We need to exercise a bit of care in discussing things like "irreducibility" in a ring with zero divisors. Bill Dubuque dug up resources in [an old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/11619). Not sure whether those articles give everything you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
(3x+4)(4x+3) = 12x^2 + 25x + 12 \equiv x \pmod{6}
$$

Comment: So, I plug x=0 in $12x^2+25x+12=0$ (mod 6) so it is reducible?

Comment: @Dom it certainly factors...

Comment: @Dom it has nothing to do with substituting $x=0.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes, so 12 is congruent to 0 and 25 to 1 so we are left with x.

Answer (score 0):

More *conceptually*, note that $\,\begin{align}f \equiv 3\\ e\equiv 4\end{align}\,$ obey $\,\begin{align}e^2\equiv&\ e,\ \ e\!+\!f \equiv 1\\ f^2\equiv&\ f,\ \ \ \   \color{#c00}{e\,f\,\equiv 0}\end{align}\ \ $ [[orthogonal idempotents]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1444473/242), so

$$ (ex\!+\!f)(fx\!+\!e)\, \equiv\, \color{#c00}{ef}\, x^2 + (e^2\!+\!f^2) x + \color{#c00}{ef}\,\equiv\, x\qquad\qquad$$

The same will occur with the idempotents arising from any CRT direct product decomposition.

Essentially what occurs is that the trivial factorization $x \equiv x\cdot 1\,$ becomes nontrivial by permuting the factors $\,x,1\,$ in each product component, as below

$$\underset{}{\overset{\Large \bmod 2:}{\phantom{I^{I^{I^{I^{I^I}}}}}}}\underbrace{\overbrace{(3x\!+\!4)}^{\Large  \equiv\ x }}_{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\Large\bmod 3:\ \ \ \ \  \equiv\ 1}\,\underbrace{\overbrace{(4x\!+\!3)}^{\Large \equiv\ 1}}_{\Large \equiv\ x}\qquad $$

where we have that $\, x\equiv gh \equiv x\cdot 1\pmod{\!2}\,$ vs. $\ gh\equiv 1\cdot x\pmod{\!3}$