# Proving that $(2k+1)$ is idempotent for $\mathbb{Z}_{2(2k+1)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, idempotents

I've noticed that the group $\mathbb{Z_n}$ under multiplication has a non-trivial idempotent element particularly when $n=2(2k+1), k \in \mathbb{N}$ --- in other words, the even numbers are twice an odd number.

**Claim:** For $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $n=2(2k+1), k \in \mathbb{N}$, $2k+1$ is idempotent

*Proof*

Let $n=2(2k+1)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ We want to show that $(2k+1)^2 = 2k+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Since $n = 0 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ we have $2(2k+1) = 0 \iff 4k+2 = 0 \iff 4k = -2$

So $4k = -2$.

Then, $$(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=k(4k)+4k+1 =k(-2)+4k+1=-2k+4k+1=2k+1$$

Thus, we have shown that $2k+1$ is idempotent in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ under multiplication  $\hspace{1cm} \square$

Comment: But $(\Bbb Z_n,\times)$ is not in general a group.

Comment: If you amend the statement to the *ring* $\mathbb{Z}_{4k+2}$ having $2k+1$ as an idempotent, then the statement is true and the proof works.

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4087186/proving-idempotent-elements-in-mathbbz-n)

Comment: Is there any question here?